# LG clothes dryer drum doesn't engage and error is shown

Tags: dryer

I have a standalone LG Dryer that when I hit More Time/Less Time the diagnostic mode reads `u12 d06`. I can hear the motor spin but the drum does not engage. What could the problem be? I've confirmed the belt is good and in working order (took off the top and saw tension and spined the drum around to inspect it).

Model number [DLEC855W](https://www.lg.com/us/dryers/lg-DLEC855W-electric-dryer).

Comment: Does the drum spin on other settings?

Comment: Nope, it heard the motor spinning until the drum engages, or tries to engage, and then I hear a grinding sound. I have confirmed the belt is good.

Answer (score 1):

Requires disassembly to check blower wheel freedom of movement. Insure that the drum rollers are operating as designed and there are no restrictions to free drum rotation.

Comment: What does the part after the comma mean?

Comment: Sorry, poor phasing!  Insure that the drum rollers are operating as designed and there are no restrictions to free drum rotation.

Comment: Great. Please [edit] that correction into your answer. Not everyone will read the comments.

Comment: Is there a basis for this answer, experience or manual? That would lend validity to your answer.

Comment: 70 years of experience taking machines apart starting with my mother's toaster!  20 years of experience repairing and selling used washers and dryers!  5 years of that last 20 full-time for a small business.